# String, substring, Range, NSRange in Swift 4

Tags: string, range, nsrange, swift4

I am using the following code to get a `String` substring from an `NSRange`:

```
func substring(with nsrange: NSRange) -> String? {
    guard let range = Range.init(nsrange)
        else { return nil }
    let start = UTF16Index(range.lowerBound)
    let end = UTF16Index(range.upperBound)
    return String(utf16[start..<end])
}
```

(via: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/12/19/nsregularexpression-and-swift/)

When I compile with Swift 4 (Xcode 9b4), I get the following errors for the two lines that declare `start` and `end`:

```
'init' is unavailable
'init' was obsoleted in Swift 4.0
```

I am confused, since I am not using an init.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use Range(_, in:) to convert an NSRange to a Range in Swift 4.

```
extension String {
    func substring(with nsrange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        guard let range = Range(nsrange, in: self) else { return nil }
        return self[range]
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode forces me to fix the code as follows: `func substring(with nsrange: NSRange) -> String? {
        guard let range = Range(nsrange, in: self) else { return nil }
        return String(self[range])
    }`

Comment: If you make the function return a Substring instead of a String, you won't have to convert the result.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize Substring is a type, I thought it was a typo.

Comment: Substring is a slice type. What that means is that it holds a reference to the original string, as well as the range that the substring represents. The advantage of a slice is that you don't have to make a copy of the data the way you would if you were returning a new String, so performance is better.

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 4 we can get substrings this way.

1. Substring from index

   ```
   let originStr = "Test"
   let offset = 1
   let str = String(originStr.suffix(from: String.Index.init(encodedOffset: offset)))
   ```
2. Substring to index

   ```
   let originStr = "Test"
   let offset = 1
   String(self.prefix(index))
   ```

Comment: Does that second example need some editing? Should `index` be `offset`

Comment: Also, it's not an answer to the question