# Why won't substrings work in Swift 4 anymore?

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta, swift4

one of the pods in my project won't compile and I can't figure out why. Truthfully, I've never had to deal with `String.UnicodeScalarView` so I have no idea what that is and the docs aren't being very helpful. They are still using `string[subscript]` in the Swift 4 documentation but Xcode is complaining about `subscript` being obsolete. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Please show your code and full error message as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String, substring, Range, NSRange in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449186/string-substring-range-nsrange-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the exact same error in exactly the same place (same Mapbox file). I believe the problem has to do with the new substring type being distinct from the String type which breaks the code at the line you indicate. I'm still trying to understand the new docs. Anyway I took a punt and tried the following, using `String.UnicodescalarView` (which I"ve not come across either)

```
encodedString = String.UnicodeScalarView(encodedString[encodedString.index(after: currentIndex)..<encodedString.endIndex])
```

Be aware that while this allows the code to compile and run, it involves unlocking a file in the pod (to allow editing) and so you should use with caution and make sure to update the pod as soon as Mapbox release an update. This isn't a long term fix at all.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll mark it as the right answer for now. At least the code compiles :p

Comment: In Swift 4, when you subscript a `String` with a range, it produce a `SubString` instead of `UnicodeScalarView` in Swift 3. I've always felt that strings in Swift are terribly designed and major releases don't do much to help. The `SubString` proposal is here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md

Comment: @Code Different - Completely agree and thanks for the link.